# Knockout page not working on mobile device

Tags: knockout.js

We just found a problem on our website where if a user connects via a mobile connection, not WIFI, the page fails.

What we have established is that the page has some minified HTML in the mobile case, with important knockout related html comments removed, so the binding falls over.

Connecting via WIFI avoids the problem, so we suspect that the mobile network operator (T-Mobile/EE) is minifying the html.

We are planning to switch all knockout html comments to attributes, but is there another possible explanation/solution, e.g server-side?

Comment: Phone browsers often remove leading and trailing comments, depending on their location in the DOM.  Post a sample of some code that is getting ignored and maybe we can offer some tips.

Comment: You can take a look at this GH issue: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1072. It has a suggestion to use in the headers that may work, if the mobile network is stripping them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I have updated the question slightly.. do you want to add that comment as an answer and I'll tick it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were experiencing this exact problem today with our mobile app.
The mobile provider was minifying our html, stripping comments including Knockouts virtual bindings.

The solution was to output the header:

**Cache-Control: no-transform**

Assuming your mobile provider will respect the header. The other alternative is to not rely on virtual bindings.

Comment: Great answer, in ASP.Net I added `        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform")` to the Page Load event and that fixed my problem.