# Virtual element not working in Safari

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, safari

The following virtual element is being used to dynamically create jQuery Mobile pages:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'page-default', foreach: metaData.tabs, afterRender: afterTabsRender } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Works in all Desktop browsers, but not in IOS or Windows Phone. I inspected the DOM in Safari on a Mac and instead of the original virtual element I only see this:

```
<!--//-->
```

However, this test page works in Safari and it uses the same virtual element: http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/eFDLr/7/

Does anybody know what is happening with the comments in Safari?

Comment: Most probably your hosting provider strips out the comments when it sends the html to mobile browsers...

Comment: If it was the provider, then the comments would also be stripped out in other browsers, but they don't.

Comment: Try faking a mobile user agent in chrome or Firefox to see if the server is stripping the comments for certain browsers.

Comment: When I spoof IPhone or IPad user agents with chrome dev tools, the comments are there and the site is working. On Safari, the HTML comments obviously get stripped, when I add additional comments to the body they disappear completely, comments in the header appear fine (I use ko templates with virtual elements in the header and they appear normally). Problem is, that I currently do not have admin access to the IIS hosting the web. I wonder if there is a way to force comments to stay intact.

Comment: Thank you for the comments which helped a lot, I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22621196/1846879

Comment: Hm, can I mark my question as a duplicate now and point to the answer I found?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout page not working on mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184869/knockout-page-not-working-on-mobile-device)